# Edit shortcode in post content programatically

Tags: shortcode

- Let's assume there is a simple post.
- It has some content and a few `[gallery]` shortcodes in it.
- I need to add (or modify) attribute to specific shortcode and **save in database** (not temporarily modify or filter) the new post content.
- So when viewing content in editor, it'll look something like this:

  - `[gallery testattribute="1"]`

Here is where I am now:

```
$post_id = 16; // Some post ID
$post_to_edit = get_post($post_id);
$content = $post_to_edit->post_content;

// find all shortcodes in the post_contnet
if ( preg_match_all( '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/s', $post_to_edit->post_content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
    foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {
        // filter only gallery shortcode
        if ( 'gallery' === $shortcode[2] ) {

            $gallery_shortcode_attributes = shortcode_parse_atts( $shortcode[3] );

            // Found the shortcode
            // need to add attribute to it
            // and modify $content variable
            // how?
        }
    }
}

// save the updated content to the database
wp_update_post( array(
    'ID'           => $post_id,
    'post_content' => $content
) );
```

I can't figure out the method to add/modify the attribute in `$content`. Should I do a simple string replacement?

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to use the default shortcode methods?

Comment: @Jeroen I need to allow admin to edit the shortcode from the frontend, and I can only modify post content.

Comment: You might try parsing the shortcode as a string, add your attributes, then pass it through `apply_filters( 'the_content', $yourcontenthere );` before displaying it on the page? I have no idea if that will work.